# How to find total number of files selected in QtDialog?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a QT application in which user can select multiple files, I receive a `QStringList` in which I have names of all the files selected, I just want to count the total number of files selected by the user. How can I do that?

Comment: use `fileDialog.selectedFiles().size()`

Comment: thnx for the quick answer. I'm new to QT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you didn't show your code, I can't assume that you are using a `QFileDialog`, event though it's probable.

That said, a `QStringList` is actually a `QList<QString>` under the hood (it [inherits](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html) from that), so that you can simply use the `size` method, as from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#size).

Comment: Thnx for the quick answer